# Advisable to run a Kafka producer + consumer in same application?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Spring + Apache Kafka noob here. I'm wondering if its advisable to run a single Spring Boot application that handles **both** producing messages as well as consuming messages.

A lot of the applications I've seen using Kafka lately usually have one separate application send/emit the message to a Kafka topic, and another one that consumes/processes the message from that topic. For larger applications, I can see a case for separate producer and consumer applications, but what about smaller ones?

For example: I'm a simple app that processes HTTP requests => send requests to a third party service, but to ensure retryability, I put the request on a Kafka queue with a service using the `@Retryable` annotation?

And what other considerations might come into play since it would be on the Spring framework?

Comment: Worth pointing out that Kafka Streams API (Spring Cloud Streams) already is both a consumer and producer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: As your question states, what'll say is more of an advice based on my beliefs and experience rather than some absolute truth written in stone.

Your use case seems more like a `proxy` than an actual application with business logic. You should *make sure that making this an asynchronous service makes sense* - maybe it's good enough to simply hold the connection until you get a response from the 3p, and let your client handle retries if you get an error - of course, you can also retry until some timeout.

This would avoid common *asynchronous issues* such as making your client need to `poll` or have a `webhook` in order to get a result, or making sure a record still makes sense to be processed after a lot of time has elapsed after an outage or a high consumer lag.

If your client doesn't care about the result as long as it gets done, and you don't expect high-throughput on either side, a single `Spring Boot` application should be enough for handling both producer and consumer sides - while also keeping it simple.

If you do expect high throughput, I'd look into building a [WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html) based application with the [reactor-kafka](https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference/) library - high throughput proxies are an excellent use case for `reactive applications`.

Another option would be having a simple `serverless function` that handles the `http` requests and produces the records, and a standard `Spring Boot` application to consume them.

<s>TBH, I don't see a use case where having two full-fledged java applications to handle a proxy duty would pay off, unless maybe you have a really sound infrastructure to easily manage them that it doesn't make a difference having two applications instead of one and using more resources is not an issue.</s>

Actually, if you expect really high traffic and a `serverless function` wouldn't work, or maybe you want to stick to Java-based solutions, then you could have a simple `WebFlux`-based application to handle the `http` requests and send the messages, and a standard `Spring Boot` or another `WebFlux` application to handle consumption. This way you'd be able to scale up the former in order to accommodate the high traffic, and independently scale the later in correspondence with your performance requirements.

As for the retry part, if you stick to non-reactive `Spring Kafka` applications, you might want to look into the [non-blocking retries feature](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic) from `Spring Kafka`. This will enable your consumer application to process other records while waiting to retry a failed one - the `@Retryable` approach is deprecated in favor of [DefaultErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#default-eh) and both will block consumption while waiting.

Note that with that you lose ordering guarantees, so use it only if the order the requests are processed is not important.

Comment: There is something to be said about a http server that forwards data to Kafka (a proxy), but a separate deployable that actually consumes that data and forwards to a remote system (e.g. Kafka Connect Cluster)

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I mean a proxy since it seems to basically only forward http requests to a 3p. I'm not that familiar with Kafka Connect Cluster, maybe you can add an answer with that approach? I'm a fan of the work you do here on SO BTW, thanks!

Comment: The question is specific to Spring, so I'd leave it. My main point is that there could be multiple services interested in consuming the data, which is the main benefit of Kafka. And Spring isn't required to be used for that. Otherwise, the question is simply asking about handling retries against unreliable downstream services

Comment: Sure. As the OP mentioned being a noob in Spring, I wanted to paint a picture with different solutions within the ecosystem. Maybe I missed the point and digressed - let's see what the OP has to say. Thanks.

Comment: Great advice .@OneCricketeer .@TomazFernandes. I'll take what you both have answered into consideration. The app is very much as Tomaz described and is sort of like a proxy, however it does contain some business logic within it. My concern with this question was the capability and reliability of having a consumer+producer in the same application since its not a pattern I've seen too often in Kafka apps. But Tomaz hits a lot of the notes I've already been considering (ordering, async behavior, non-blocking retries)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @quirkworx, I'm glad it was helpful. I've edited my answer with yet another scenario that came to mind - maybe it's helpful too. Thanks.